# Vba making summary table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, summary, top-n

I want to discuss an issue about my VBA code. I am trying to retrieve top 5 workers of each shift based on dpmo column as shown in the data:

[image: Data]

and summarizing them into a summary table:

[image: Table].

The issue I am having is that my summary table is correctly summarizing the values only if each group has 5 or more than 5 values otherwise it is taking the next group values and inserting them into the previous group. I want top organize the table in such a way that if a group has less than 5 values then the remaing rows of that group should be filled with "-"(e.g if the group has only two values in dataframe then other three values of that group should be "-").Here is my code.

```vb
Sub tgr()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim rngUnqGroups As Range
    Dim GroupCell As Range
    Dim lCalc As XlCalculation
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim aOriginal As Variant
    Dim lNumTopEntries As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, k As Long

    
    lNumTopEntries = 5

    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")    
    'Set wsDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")    

    Set rngData = wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp))
    aOriginal = rngData.Value   'Store original values so you can set them back later'

    'With Application
     '   lCalc = .Calculation
      '  .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       ' .EnableEvents = False
        '.ScreenUpdating = False
    'End With


    On Error GoTo CleanExit

    'With rngData
     '   .sort .Resize(, 6).Offset(, 0), xlAscending, .Resize(, 6).Offset(, 0), , xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    'End With

    With rngData.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 0)
        .AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, , , True
        Set rngUnqGroups = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Parent.ShowAllData 'Remove the filter

        ReDim aResults(1 To rngUnqGroups.Cells.Count * lNumTopEntries, 1 To 7)
        I = 0

        For Each GroupCell In rngUnqGroups
            Set rngFound = .Find(GroupCell.Value, .Cells(.Cells.Count))
            k = 0
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                For J = I + 1 To I + lNumTopEntries
                    If rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1).Value = GroupCell.Value Then
                        k = k + 1
                        'aResults(j, 1) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1, -1).Value
                        aResults(J, 2) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1).Value
                        aResults(J, 3) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 1).Value
                        aResults(J, 4) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 2).Value
                        aResults(J, 5) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 3).Value
                        aResults(J, 6) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 4).Value
                        aResults(J, 7) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 5).Value
                    End If
                Next J
                I = I + k
            End If
        Next GroupCell
    End With


    wsData.Range("G:Z").Clear
    wsData.Range("K5").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

CleanExit:
  
    With Application
        .Calculation = lCalc
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error: " & Err.Number
        Err.Clear
    End If

    
    rngData.Value = aOriginal
'Call summ_table
End Sub
```

It would be appreciating if somebody can help me in my code. Please also note that the reason column and top column are inserted after retrieving top values.

Answer (score 0):

Move `k = k + 1`.

Instead of this

```
For J = I + 1 To I + lNumTopEntries
    If rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1).Value = GroupCell.Value Then
        k = k + 1
        'aResults(j, 1) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1, -1).Value
        aResults(J, 2) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1).Value
        aResults(J, 3) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 1).Value
        aResults(J, 4) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 2).Value
        aResults(J, 5) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 3).Value
        aResults(J, 6) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 4).Value
        aResults(J, 7) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 5).Value
    End If
Next J
```

use this:

```
For J = I + 1 To I + lNumTopEntries
    If rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1).Value = GroupCell.Value Then
        'aResults(j, 1) = rngFound.Offset(j - i - 1, -1).Value
        aResults(J, 2) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1).Value
        aResults(J, 3) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 1).Value
        aResults(J, 4) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 2).Value
        aResults(J, 5) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 3).Value
        aResults(J, 6) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 4).Value
        aResults(J, 7) = rngFound.Offset(J - I - 1, 5).Value
    End If
    k = k + 1
Next J
```

Comment: BTW, I like very much the way you designed your `CleanExit` part.

Comment: many thanks for comment but now I am skipping other groups when I modify my code as you suggested and I want to keep them as well